# Convert Lua code to C++

Tags: c++, lua

I currently have this code:

```
PACKETS = {};

function AddPacket(data)
    local id = data.ID;
    PACKETS[id] = {
    data.IP,
    data.PORT,
    data.PACKET,
    data.SOURCEIP,
    data.SOURCEPORT,
    data.PPMS};
end

function RemovePacket(id)
    PACKETS[id] = nil;
end

function LoopedThread()
    for k,v in pairs(PACKETS) do
        for i=1, v.PPMS do
            SendPacket(v.IP, v.PORT, v.PACKET, v.SOURCEIP, v.SOURCEPORT);
        end
    end
    Sleep(1);
end
```

This was done in lua as an example, however I'm needing this done in C++. I'm a little confused as I cant get it to work when trying to make it, if someone could help me out or even get me started, thanks.

I already have the sockets coded.

Comment: Erm, so you wrote some C++ code, it doesn't work and you thought it was a good idea to post complete different code that does work instead?

Comment: It was an example, I don't want it done in LUA, I want it in C++

Comment: There's no automated way to do it and there's no right or wrong way either. Your answer depends on a large number of factors (compiler, os, libraries, context, etc) so it's unlikely you'll get a helpful answer. Try to break your question into smaller questions each dealing with a precise requirement and some code you wrote to try and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you at all familiar with the [Standard Template Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) in C++? It probably has a bunch of container types that might help you accomplish what you're trying.

To me, it looks like what you're doing would be accomplished by implementing a "Packet" struct or class that contained member variables "IP", "PORT", and so on.

Then if you wanted to store them and access them by their ID, you could create an [stl::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) that maps from the ID numbers to the Packets.

Or, as is common with packets, you might eventually want to store them in a first-in, first-out manner, which can be done with a [stl::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue).  With the queue they come out in the same order you put them in, so if you queue up packets 1, 2, and 3 and later go to access two of them, you will get packets 1 and 2 in that order, and 3 will still be left for later.

My C++ is pretty rusty, but I'm thinking of something like this:

```
struct Packet {
    char* ip;
    short port;
    // ... etc ...
}

stl::queue<Packet> packet_buffer;

void AddPacket(const Packet& packet_in) {
    packet_buffer.push(packet_in);
}

void RemoveLastPacket() {
    packet_buffer.pop();
}

void LoopedThread() {
    while (!packet_buffer.empty()) {
        SendPacket(packet_buffer.front());
        RemoveLastPacket();
    }
}
```

You could do something similar with a map, but it would be slower and less efficient. Unless you *really* need to look up a particular packet based on its ID, I would stick with a queue, which can be staggeringly fast.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just integrate Lua with C/C++? This language was build to easily integrate with C/C++ and it's quite common practice in game development. I would recommend you to use `luabind`. It's a Lua version of `boost::python` library. Link: vhttp://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html